# VSCode flutter how to launch Android Emulator instead of Chrome

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

All my old projects were able to launch debugging with Android Emulator. When I press F5, it will shows a list of installed Android Emulator for me to select for debugging.

But today, I have created a new project, and it launches debugging in Chrome instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. First you'll need to check if the android platform has been initialized for the project. If you project has an android folder then it has been initialized, if you will need to create it with the following command: `flutter create --platforms android .`
2. To run the emulator, check the bottom right corner of the screen you should see the currently selected platform, if you click on the selected platform a pop up should appear allowing you to select from all supported platforms.
3. You can also you use *quick-open* (`ctrl+p`) and type in `>flutter launch emulator`, if no emulator is found it will provide you the option to create one as well.

[image: screenshot of vs-code connected devices]

Comment: I just found out that there is a new option in Run->Open Configuration, after that in the lower right of the screen **Add Configuration** select Android Devices, and then restart VSCode to take effect.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default from `Chrome (web-javascript)` to `Android Emulator`?

Comment: Yes this one solved the issue, before I set default port for my web, then I forgot it. Now when I try to run on android, it opened the chrome with that specicif port always.